# how to use php to get data from a input form preset data?

Tags: php, html, field

I have below pre-set data inside the input field.  I want to get the 20 from the "validate-item-blank-quantity" -> "minAllowed".

Is it possible to use Php to get value from there?

Thanks

```
    <input type="number" name="qty_custom" id="qty_custom" value="" title="Quantity" class="input-text qty mage-error" data-validate="{"required-number":true,"validate-item-quantity":{"minAllowed":1,"maxAllowed":1000000,"qtyIncrements":1},"validate-item-blank-quantity":{"minAllowed":20,"maxAllowed":1000000,"qtyIncrements":10}}" aria-invalid="true" aria-describedby="qty_custom-error">
```

Comment: You can only get the name and value from that input field with php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As lewis4 pointed in the comment you can send only `name` and `value` attributes. Anyway, you can use simple JS to create new `hidden` field and send with data from other attributes.

Assuming, that value of `data-validate` is always valid JSON, that should work:

HTML

```
<form action="yourscript.php" id="myform" method="post">
    <input type="number" name="qty_custom" id="qty_custom" value="" title="Quantity" class="input-text qty mage-error" data-validate='{"required-number":true,"validate-item-quantity":{"minAllowed":1,"maxAllowed":1000000,"qtyIncrements":1},"validate-item-blank-quantity":{"minAllowed":20,"maxAllowed":1000000,"qtyIncrements":10}}' aria-invalid="true" aria-describedby="qty_custom-error">
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>

<script>
    $('[data-validate]').each(function () {
        let $el = $(this);
        $('#myform').append("<input type='hidden' name='" + $el.attr('name') + '[data-validate]' + "' value='" + $el.attr('data-validate') + "' />");
    });
</script>
```

PHP `yourscript.php`

```
<?php
if (!is_null($_POST) && !is_null($_POST['qty_custom']['data-validate'])) {
    $arr = json_decode($_POST['qty_custom']['data-validate'], true);
    echo "Minimal value is: " . $arr['validate-item-quantity']['minAllowed'], '<br>';
    echo "Maximal value is: " . $arr['validate-item-quantity']['maxAllowed'], '<br>';
}
```

Don't forget to include jQuery in your `head`

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**WARNING:**

Remember that if you want to make some server-side validation you should not to send it via your request as it can be easily manipulated, so validation can be changed or even skipped.

Comment: thanks! for the javascript,  myform = my form name, what about the name? since my form has few input field. From your sample the name should I change it to qty_custom ? thanks

Comment: Sorry, there is a fix in my sample, of course, that field created with JS should be a `hidden` type. You do not need to change any name of the field. The script is easy, it finds all fields with `data-validate` attribute and creates hidden fields with an extended name like `somefield[data-validate]`. `myform` is the id of the form, in jQuery, you select it with `$('#myform')`

Comment: Thanks! this is very helpful and I learn something!

Comment: If you'll find it useful, feel free to accept the answer.

Comment: Also, I added some warning at the end of the post, consider if passing validation arguments from client-side to server-side is secure conception in your case.